# Dataflow workers failing to fetch containers from GCR

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Just got this error message:

> (941d0d42ab1c3aec): Workflow failed. Causes: (941d0d42ab1c3675): The Dataflow appears to be stuck. Please reach out to the Dataflow team at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow.

please help.

Comment: job id:  2017-09-11_07_13_42-2005096921586938573

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the job id. From the Stackdriver logs, I see that worker VMs failed to startup becuase they were not able to fetch the container image from docker:

```
Handler for GET /v1.23/images/dataflow.gcr.io/v1beta3/beam-java-batch:beam-0.6.0/json returned error: No such image: dataflow.gcr.io/v1beta3/beam-java-batch:beam-0.6.0
```

**EDIT:** After further inspection, I can see there are no staged jars for the job. It seems the stagingFiles is being overrriden with just a csv file: `header_H-[..].csv`.

If you are specifying the `getFilesToStage()` option, you must also include the full list of jar files necessary to run your pipeline. You can see how the `DataflowRunner` does this in [`detectClassPathResourcesToStage(classLoader)`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.1.0/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowRunner.java#L1340).

---

As an aside, this pipeline is using the Dataflow SDK 0.6, which is currently deprecated. The latest 1.x release is [1.9.1](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-java-1), or you can upgrade to [2.1.0](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-java-2) which is based on [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/).

Comment: yes, i can provide whatever you need to know about this pipeline, just let me know what details you need. there is no firewall configuration or anything that I know will block the access to docker images. In regard to SDK 0.6, i have two questions: 1) is it still available to use  2) I have problem of running anything with version > 0.6 on my local machine where I use to debug my program locally.

Comment: I asked some other Dataflow engineers, and it seems that VMs can get corrupted and fail to spin up from time-to-time. Do you still encounter the issue same if you re-run the job?

Comment: For your questions on upgrading from 0.6: 1) yes, 1.6.0 is deprecated though still available to run jobs. The 1.6.0 release has known data loss issues with compressed sources so it's highly recommended users upgrade. See: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-java-1  If you encounter issues upgrading, please start a new question.

Comment: As you hinted, if i use `--filesToStage`, I must include the full list of jar files necessary to run your pipeline, in my case, i just want to add a few files to the the stage location, so I used `--filesToStage=myfiles.csv`. if I omitted this option all necessary jar files determined by the maven pom.xml (161 of them) will be automatically added to stage. If I do use this option to specify the additional myfiles.csv, then those 161 jar will not be added. so how can I add additional files without explicitly specifying the jar files maven determine?

Comment: `--filesToStage` is indeed difficult to use and only recommended if your resources cannot be easily expressed as part of the maven build. If `myfiles.csv` is data being processed by your pipeline, you should upload it to a cloud directory such as Google Cloud Storage and read from there. Otherwise, you can add it to the JAR as a resource; here's an example: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

Comment: Scott, using file from resources folder instead of using --filesToStage has resolved this issue. thank you so much.